# Error when migrating: 'There is already an object named 'table_name' in the database.'

Tags: sql-server, django

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to migrate on an Azure SQL Server db.  This project also has a local mysql database and relationships between the two DB's but that doesn't seem to be at issue here

I've tried deleting and squashing the migrations.  I've tried --fake-initial.  I have realized, though, that the issue is just that django isn't preventing itself from trying to create the table if it already exists during the migration.

I'm curious if there's a setting to prevent django from just sending a create command during the migration if the table already exists.

For now since I'm just developing I can just nuke the DB and start over, but this isn't going to work if I modify a column and try to migrate it in production

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Check out explanation regarding `--fake` vs. `--fake-initial` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained)

Comment: maybe you tried to delete and squash migrations and they don't match anymore with your DB. Try to migrate on a fresh new created db.