# Recreate deleted django_migrations table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am building a Django web application and I dropped the table django_migrations using psql command line and I want to recreate it.

Comment: `manage.py migrate --fake …` and `--fake-initial` might be helpful. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)

Comment: Thank you, I have used `python manage.py migrate --fake` and it worked and recreated the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recreate django_migrations simply use

```
./manage.py migrate --fake
```

But please be careful with that as mentioned here:

> If you break something, nobody can help you probably, because the
> migration system will not know the current state of the database more.
> Therefore do a backup, write notes, use a sandbox and work precisely.

[Django migrate --fake and --fake-initial explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained)

Comment: Thank you it worked, I updated a model fields when I access it it shows an error that % field doesnt exist, how can this be fixed?