# An operational error when making django AJAX likes

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the error that I got.

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: photos_post_likes

I was following this video to create a like button. https://youtu.be/pkPRtQf6oQ8

By then I had already created the model (Post). Just when I added a new line (likes) in models.py and ran makemigrations, it migrated without any problem. But, when I ran migrate this error appeared.

Here is the models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Post(models.Model):
    date_shared = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes') # this line made the error occur
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 800 or img.width > 800:
            output_size = (800, 800)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

I won't waste time going into deep what the command does exactly, as you can find
a great post about the topic right here: [Django migrate --fake and --fake-initial explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained)

if the error still should occur, you should delete all files located inside your **migrations** folder **(except for **init**.py)**, and after that delete all tables inside your Database.

Afterwards simply run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

again and everything should work.
But bear in mind that by deleting your tables you will of course also lose all data/queries saved in those.

Let me know if that worked for you, because it did many times before for me.

Comment: It didn't delete anything. Should I delete it manually now?

Comment: @Poornaka What exactly do you mean  with 'It'?

Comment: @Poornaka well, if the command 'python manage.py migrate --fake' did not solve the issue for you, then you should connect to your database and delete the tables manully via SQL. If you tell what kind of SQL-DB you're using I could even tell you how to do so.

Comment: Wait...did you mean it will delete the migrations folder in the project or the app? (the command)

Comment: @Poornaka No, read carefully.  Step 1: Delete all files except '__init__.py' inside the 'migrations' folder located in your app. Step 2: Manually delete all tables in your database. Step 3: Rerun the commands 'python manage.py makemigrations' and 'python manage.py migrate'.

Comment: By did not work I mean : `python manage.py migrate --fake` works. But makemigrations command says that there are no changes detected. The same when running migrations.When I go to the admin page and try to edit a post. The error occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227473/discussion-between-poornaka-and-bialomazur).