# Why do i keep encountering this error when i try to migrate on django app

Tags: python, django, django-models

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: theblog_categories

i expected to migrate succesfully

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more information about your problem, like related app models, existing app migratios etc. also please read  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the migrations in Django are little complex and often with little changes it doesn't reflect the changes in the DB.

Please delete Migrations file from the Django app and then migrate it again.
You can also refer this link if the problem persist:
[Django migrate --fake and --fake-initial explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained)

If the problem still persist please reply to this comment.