# How to solve the problem django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNE17.png)

I just wanna add other attribute to model

```
class BookCardsModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Card Books'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Card Books'

    book_cover = models.ImageField()
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    full_description = models.TextField(max_length=700)
    book_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    book_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    book_size = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
```

Comment: Did you delete your database table and recreate it?  Django doesn't know your description no longer matches the table.

Comment: Yes I did but it appears no such column

Comment: I'm suspicious.  Have you checked in the database to see if the new column now exists?

Comment: Digital field has already in database but i don't add any infor to this table

Answer (score 2):

After updating the django models, you'll need to create new migrations and then migrate

you can use following commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations # to make migrations
python manage.py migrate # to migrate
```

then your actual DB would be updated and new columns will be added

Comment: Yes I've done already but it didn't work

Comment: what's the error, is it the same as asked in question or something else

Comment: Yes same error in this question

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your recent migration file to check the required columns have applied or not.
If yes, Do you make migrations as [Ayush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76950221/14080492).

If problem still persists, Maybe You've messed up your migrations files. You can fake migration

```
python manage.py migrate --fake appname migration
```

Be careful while applying --fake or --fake-intial on migrations

You can read in detail here:
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774336/)

If problem still persists, Consider uploading migrations and error logs in question which can used to resolve faster by anyone.

Comment: Thanks you . That's great way but it didn't work until I delete filed of database